OBS Window Not Appearing; Running as Background Task
I am trying to run OBS Studio on my Windows 11 device, but whenever I run the program (from desktop, Program Files, or from the Windows search bar) it opens as a background task, taking up very little memory and CPU.
Task manager screenshot
Running OBS worked fine for the first few times, then all my settings were deleted, then it stopped showing up in a window or in the task bar entirely.
However, when I run OBS with the background app already being shown/run in task manager, it shows the "OBS is already running" window with the two launch anyway and cancel options. When I chose the launch anyway option, it opened up a new background app similar to the one already running.
I have tried to fix the program by uninstalling / reinstalling OBS, and using different methods to reinstall it (Microsoft Store and from the OBS Studio webpage), but they all result in the background app problem again. After uninstalling OBS, I make sure that the Program Files and Desktop Shortcut are deleted, and have used the uninstall.exe file as well as hard-deleting the entirety of Program Files and the Desktop Shortcut.
However, I think something must still remain after uninstalling because whenever I download a new version of OBS Studio and run it, it gives me an option to Run in Safe Mode or Run Normally because the popup says that OBS shut down improperly. I've tried both options, but neither does anything except running the same background app.
Any help would be much appreciated!
P.S. Sorry if this isn't the right SE site for this, I'm new here.

I had something similar the other day, I suspect it was because I checked the Hide OBS Windows from capture option.
You can modify it in the .INI file in C:\Users\[your-name]\AppData\Roaming\obs-studio, it is named HideOBSWindowsFromCapture.
Next to that, I think the OBS icon in the taskbar also has options to bring windows in view.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
